# Error while doing CRUD operation using Rest web API on access specifier

Tags: asp.net, postman

I am getting this exception when I am trying to send the URL in postman :

{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UserController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Type 'CP_API.Controllers.UserController' does not have a default constructor",
"ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
}
}

```
namespace CP_API.Controllers
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {         
            private readonly IDataAccessProvider _dataAccessProvider;          
            private UserController(IDataAccessProvider dataAccessProvider)
            {              
                _dataAccessProvider = dataAccessProvider;
            }

            [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<tbl_user_master> Get()
            {
                return _dataAccessProvider.GetUserRecords();
            }

            [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Create([System.Web.Http.FromBody] UserModel tbl_User_Master)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    String guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() ;
                    tbl_User_Master.user_id = Convert.ToInt32(guid); 
                    _dataAccessProvider.AddUserRecord(tbl_User_Master);
                //return System.Web.Http.Results.StatusCodeResult;
                return (IActionResult)Ok();
                }
                return (IActionResult)BadRequest();
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Rutuparna Panda

Comment: After doing this step a parameterless constructor has created but i got an exception:      {
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44390/api/user'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request."
}

Comment: I am getting the same exception also after changing the URL.

Comment: Did you create the User action? From your controller I am not able to see `User` action method.